# How to get total number of hours between two dates in sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime

Consider two dates `2010-03-18 22:30:45` and `2010-03-19 03:30:15` .... How to get the number of hours and minutes in between the two dates in sql server.....

Answer (score 23, accepted):

@codeka answered with the hours part (from your title) but in the body of your question you asked for hours and minutes so, here is one way

```
 select DATEDIFF(hh, @date1, @date2) as Hours_Difference,   
    DATEDIFF(mi,DATEADD(hh,DATEDIFF(hh, @date1, @date2),@date1),@date2) as Minutes_Difference
```

What this does in the first part is what @codeka showed.  It gives you the datediff between the two dates in actual full hours.  The second term in the sql gives the datediff in minutes between the (first date + the hours elapsed) and the second date. You have to eliminate the hours from the equation in the minutes part or you will get the actual minutes between the dates.  Datediff and its allowed Datepart identifiers can be researched here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: I don't see how the Minutes DIFF works here. It looks over the top. Why not simply DATEDIFF(mi, Date1, Date2)? That worked for me.

Comment: The question asked for hours and minutes between dates if they had asked for just minutes between dates what you proposed would work.

Answer (score 6):

You want the [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hh, @date1, @date2)
```

Comment: DATEDIFF will return almost any datepart according to the specification here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The problem with [William Salzman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236348/william-salzman)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2475263/1459471) is that it returns strange answers if the first time is not on the hour. So 10:30 to 12:00 gives 2 hours and -30 minutes.

If that isn't what you want, then this will give you 1 hour and 30 minutes:

```
select 
    CONVERT(int,DATEDIFF(mi, @date1, @date2) / 60) as Hrs_Difference,
    CONVERT(int,DATEDIFF(mi, @date1, @date2) % 60) as Mins_Difference
```

Comment: Actually it should be this:
    `select 
        CONVERT(int,DATEDIFF(hour, @date1, @date2) / 60) as Hrs_Difference,
        CONVERT(int,DATEDIFF(mi, @date1, @date2) % 60) as Mins_Difference`

Answer (score 0):

DATEDIFF function will solve your problem of getting hours difference.

you can check this as :

```
select DATEDIFF(hh, getdate()-1, GETDATE()) HoursDifference
```

It will give you result of 24 hours

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are various ways to answer this, but for me, I've always believe in the notion of starting small - as in get the overall value and then **convert it UP** to the answer you want.

Assuming `date2` is greater than `date1`:

A simple mathematical difference multiplied by 24 hours in a day works:

```
CAST(date2 - date1 as NUMERIC(18,4)) * 24.00 AS [HrsDiff]
```

Or using Will's answer using [min] for minutes:

```
CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, date1, date2) AS NUMERIC(18,4)) / 60 AS [HrsDiff]
```

So the minute total is divided by 60 to give you the hours.

The first option gives you a big decimal, whereas the 2nd option rounds it up to the nearest decimal.