# How to get the number of hours between the two dates in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get the number of hours between the two dates in SQL Server

Example:

```
staffing_start_date (2017-08-01 06:00:00.00000)
staffing_end_dt (2017-08-01 18:00:00.00000)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get total number of hours between two dates in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475178/how-to-get-total-number-of-hours-between-two-dates-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 5):

You would use `datediff()`:

```
select datediff(hour, staffing_start_date, staffing_end_date)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need the number of fractional hours, you can use below

```
DATEDIFF(second, staffing_start_date, staffing_end_date) / 3600.0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. You can check this as the answer to close this inquiry. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See `DATEDIFF` function - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql.

For your question, you can use:

- `DATEDIFF` `( HOUR, staffing_start_date , staffing_end_dt )`
- `DATEDIFF` `( HH, staffing_start_date , staffing_end_dt )`

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware of DateDiff's unexpected gotcha though.  It does no rounding at all.  It will truncate to the level you are looking for (Day, hour, min etc)

For example, both of these will return 1, so rounding Ferdinand's answer is a better fit most of the time.

```
declare @Start DateTime = '1/1/17 7:59 AM'
Declare @End Datetime = '1/1/17 8:00 AM'
select DATEDIFF(hour, @Start, @end)


declare @Start DateTime = '1/1/17 7:01 AM'
Declare @End Datetime = '1/1/17 8:59 AM'
select DATEDIFF(hour, @Start, @end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jay Wheeler for your comments.

If you want hour to be very specific, you can use as given below:

    `Declare @Start DateTime = '1/1/17 7:59 AM' 
    Declare @End Datetime = '1/1/17 8:00 AM' 
    select DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @Start, @end) /60  AS Hour`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you didn't understand the other answers, you can use `DATEDIFF`.

Answer (score 0):

Dates are just numbers. The integral part of the number is the date and the fraction is the time. To get a difference in days, you can just cast to `int` and to get the difference in hours multiply by 24.

```
DECLARE @Date1 DateTime
DECLARE @Date2 DateTime

SELECT @Date1 =  {ts '2017-08-29 00:00:00.000'},
       @Date2 =  {ts '2017-08-27 00:00:00.000'}

SELECT  CONVERT(int, @Date1) - CONVERT(int, @Date2)        AS DifferenceInDays

SELECT (CONVERT(int, @Date1) - CONVERT(int, @Date2)) * 24  AS DifferenceInHours
```

Or you could use [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql).